# exercise on vectors of discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

How would you do the following exercise?

You toss a fair coin three times. Let X be the r.v. which counts the total number of heads and Y the r.v. which counts the number of heads of the last toss. Calculate the product density function of $(X,Y$ and the marginal ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $\mathbb{P}(\text{head}) =p$.

If $Y=0$, then $X$ can be at most $2$ therefore for $i=0,1,2$

$$
\mathbb{P}(X=i,Y=0) = \mathbb{P}(X=i|Y=0)\mathbb{P}(Y=0) = {2\choose i}p^{i}(1-p)^{2-i} (1-p),
$$
If $Y=1$, then $X$ has to be at least $1$ therefore for $i=1,2,3$

$$
\mathbb{P}(X=i,Y=1) = \mathbb{P}(X=i|Y=1)\mathbb{P}(Y=1) = {2\choose i-1}p^{i-1}(1-p)^{2-i+1} p.
$$

Comment: How do you formilize the space of the events $\Omega$? the space of {head,tail}^3 ?

Comment: The random variable that you have specified can only take certain values. For example, if $Y=0$ then the possible outcomes are $\{HHT,HTT,THT,TTT\}$, if $Y=1$ then the possible outcomes are $\{TTH,HTH,THH,HHH\}$.

Comment: yes I see thanks!